# VBA code to create Pivot Tables works on Excel 365 [Mac] but not on Excel Professional Pro Suite [PC]

Tags: vba, excel, office365, pivot-table

I am having a difficulty trying to get my code to work on the Excel Professional Pro for PC. I have changed a lot of the settings regarding the compatibility of the code between 365 and Professional Pro and have learned that the 365 automatically updates while the Professional Pro doesn't. Also, the weirdest thing is that I developed a code similar to the one below and it works. I have saved the workbook as Excel Enabled-Macro Workbook as well as Excel Enabled-Macro Template. I have no idea what to do. Please help. The code works as a button [Not an ActiveX button].

```
Sub Button1_Click()

'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long


'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("US MASTER").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "US MASTER"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("US MASTER")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("US Master Macro")

'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'
'Pivot Table 1
'

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Range("B3"), _
TableName:="Total Backlog", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Range("B3"), TableName:="Total Backlog")

'Add PR ID to Values Field
With PSheet.PivotTables("Total Backlog").PivotFields("PR ID")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Function = xlCount
.Position = 1
End With

'Add Classified Cases in Ranges to Row Field
PSheet.PivotTables("Total Backlog").AddFields _
RowFields:=Array("Classified Cases in Ranges")

'Sort Pivot Table
With PSheet
.Range("C4:C100").Sort Key1:=.Range("C4"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
End With

'Add Total Backlog
PSheet.Range("B2").Value = "Total Backlog"
PSheet.Range("B3").Value = "Days"
'Color
PSheet.Range("B2").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
'Merge
PSheet.Range("B2:C2").Merge

'Change the Color
PSheet.Range("B3").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
PSheet.Range("C3").Interior.ColorIndex = 4


End Sub
```

Comment: That is way too much code to look through! Do you have same input in your different versions? What about date and number formats?

Comment: Sam, I cut the code down to the part where I apply the Pivot Table Code. I have the same input in both in Mac 365 and Professional Pro. I only have number formats but I don't understand the connection...

Comment: The first thing to do is to remove the `On Error Resume Next`. That statement tells VBA to ignore all errors - which is exactly what you don't want.

Comment: Now I get another error [Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object defined error] on the loop 
`If Worksheets(1).Cells(x, 13) = "" Then
    Worksheets(1).Cells(x, 18) = "(blank)"
    ElseIf (Worksheets(1).Cells(x, 13) >= 0 And Worksheets(1).Cells(x, 13) <= 9) Then
    Worksheets(1).Cells(x, 18) = "0-9"
    ElseIf (Worksheets(1).Cells(x, 13) >= 10 And Worksheets(1).Cells(x, 13) <= 19) Then
    Worksheets(1).Cells(x, 18) = "10-19"
    
    End If
Next x`

Comment: Please work in your code in your question - it is not easy to read code in comments. After that - check the value of x. Is it perhaps 0?

Comment: The value of x = 2 and I declare the Dim as Long.